# Convergence of second moment over an expanding set

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, moment-problem

Suppose $X$ to be a real random variable with $E(X)=0$ and $E(X^2)=1$.

How can I prove:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}E(X^2\mathbb{I}_{\{X^2\ge n\}})=0$

I am thinking, with no success, about these results:

- monotone convergence for decreasing functions
- integral over a set of measure zero is zero for a non negative function

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What were your thoughts on monotone convergence for decreasing functions?

Comment: Being the function inside the expectation decreasing and lower bounded by zero, I can put the limit inside the expectation. Then I have a set whose values are greater than infinity. This is not possible since the expectation is finite and so the result is zero. It seems to me too informal. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like you're on the right track, but I'm not sure what you mean by "a set whose values are greater than infinity."  What is the pointwise limit of $X^21_{X^2 \ge n}$?

Comment: The pointwise limit should be $X^2 1_{X^2\ge \infty}$. But I am not sure.

Comment: Then I think the limit is zero because $E(X)<\infty$ implies that $X<\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right

Comment: Thank you for giving me the chance to prove my own arguments. It is very valuable since I am studying these things alone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, we know that since $E[X^2] < \infty$ we must have $X^2 < \infty$ a.s.  This implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X^2(\omega) 1_{X^2(\omega) \ge n} = 0$ for a.e. $\omega$.  Since $X^2 1_{X^2 \ge n}$ is a decreasing sequence of random variables bounded from below by $0$, by the monotone convergence theorem we have $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X^2 1_{X^2 \ge n}] =  E[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X^2 1_{X^2 \ge n}] = 0. $$